# Make constructor return subclass

Tags: typescript

```
class A{
    constructor(input: string) {
        // do stuff
    }
    f() {console.log("A")}
}    
class B extends A{
    constructor(input: string) {
        // do stuff
    }
    f() {console.log("B")}
}
class C extends A{
    constructor(input: string) {
        // do stuff
    }
    f() {console.log("C")}
}
```

I currently have the following setup. This might sound weird, but I would like calling `new A(inp)` to return me an instance of B or C according to the input (even if it's returned `as A` according to TypeScript) so that calling `(new A("B")).f()` will print "B", the same for passing "C", while the default is "A". Is this possible in a way that doesn't violate anything horribly? At the moment I am using a static method in A to achieve this, but I thought using the constructor would be neater.

Comment: "*Is this possible in a way that doesn't violate anything horribly?*" No

Comment: Thought so - I guess I will keep my static method approach then, unless there is an even better way.

Comment: why do subclass constructors take `input`, if the point of `input` is which subclass to produce?

Comment: You can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9yPqN) I guess.  It's a concern that the `A` constructor is necessarily doing double duty: it needs to be called as `super()` from subclass constructors, but it's also being called externally to possibly get subclass instances.  If the `B` constructor calls `super("B")` then you're in big trouble.  The actually "neater" solution is probably to continue to use your static method and make the `A` constructor protected, so that there's a separation of concerns.  If this all makes sense I can write up an answer; if not let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: That sounds like what I wanted, thanks! I didn't realize I could return objects in constructors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a [class `constructor` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor) explicitly `return`s an object other than `this`, then when you use [the `new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#description) on the class constructor, you will get that object instead of the new one created (which is called `this` inside the body of the constructor method).

```
class Foo {
  fooProp: string;
  constructor() {
    this.fooProp = "abc" // initialize fooProp on the new object
    return {
      fooProp: "zyx", // but return something completely different
    }
  };
}
const f = new Foo();
console.log(f.fooProp) // zyx, not abc
```

This is not very common, and has some surprising consequences, such as that the value you get from `new`ing a constructor is not necessarily an `instanceof` that constructor:

```
console.log(new Foo() instanceof Foo) // false !
```

People tend to avoid doing this unless they have a compelling reason.  (It's up to you to decide if your reason is compelling enough).

TypeScript does let you `return` in a `constructor` method as long as the object returned is of a type assignable to the class type.  In your case that's fine, because you are explicitly returning subclasses.  So on the face of it, yes this is possible.

---

Here's one way to do it:

```
class A {
  constructor(input?: string) {
    if (input === "B") return new B();
    if (input === "C") return new C();
  }
  f() { console.log("A") }
}
class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
  f() { console.log("B") }
}
class C extends A {
  // still has implicit constructor that calls super
  f() { console.log("C") }
}

const a = new A().f(); // A
const b = new A("B").f(); // B
const c = new A("C").f(); // C
```

I made `A`'s constructor parameter optional, and made `B` and `C` not take any constructor parameters.  If you call the `A` constructor with the exact strings `"B"` or `"C"` you get the subclass instances, otherwise you get a direct instance of `A`.  And since `B` and `C` instances are also `instanceof A`, then you don't get the bizarre behavior that `new A("B") instanceof A === false` as mentioned above.  Let's test it:

```
const a = new A();
a.f(); // A
const b = new A("B");
b.f(); // B
const c = new A("C");
c.f(); // C

console.log(a instanceof A); // true
console.log(b instanceof A); // true
console.log(c instanceof A); // true
```

So that works exactly was you want.

---

But it's a bit concerning to me because `A`'s constructor has two quite different roles and if you mix them up then bad things can happen.  The subclass constructors `B` and `C` must call [the `super()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super#syntax) either explicitly (as in `B`) or implicitly (as in `C`), so you end up with the equivalent of `new A()` called where you really only want a direct instance of `A`.  Meanwhile external callers sometimes want a `B` or a `C`.  If you accidentally confuse these roles and do this:

```
class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super("B") //  TOO MUCH RECURSION
  }
}
```

then you get infinite regress and a runtime error.

But that's the answer to the question as asked.

---

You might want to consider instead making `A`'s `constructor` [a `protected` method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#protected) and then use a `static` method to choose a constructor to call.  Such as:

```
class A {
  protected constructor() { }
  f() { console.log("A") }
  public static make(input?: string) {
    if (input === "B") return new B();
    if (input === "C") return new C();
    return new A();
  }
}
class B extends A {
  f() { console.log("B") }
}
class C extends A {
  f() { console.log("C") }
}

const a = A.make();
a.f(); // A
const b = A.make("B");
b.f(); // B
const c = A.make("C");
c.f(); // C

console.log(a instanceof A); // true
console.log(b instanceof A); // true
console.log(c instanceof A); // true
```

The behavior is similar, although external callers use `A.make(xxx)` instead of `new A(xxx)`, which is exclusively used by the class implementations themselves.  This is more or less what you're already doing, as far as I can tell.  It might not be as "neat" as using the constructor directly, but it's a lot more straightforward for people to understand what's going on.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkvBiFFEgGID21ehRSAZrQAoBO1MAXElAC7sAlsADmAbgZF41YAPYBXeP2rsAFAEp6jRvwAWQqADoW1DlyQBeJACIQAI3g2pjdhH4L2wbTsanzPLZYAJ4AHjYANC5EAL4uMZKxDDJy-MxWSMAQAO5UtJqJxLJQ1BgQRhjUompMJmycMFoA9E1IIaHJxaXlldVZuTTUmkgiAiDAiNRMedTNrUyYUMgAhPgMoJCwCMgA8sKi9C4kZBQAgj46KfJKKuoiMAr8APy88iKiWgS+jELTavePKyWaw2ABCNi0bg8XkyOSQoIK0R+fwBaWBIIAwhCkFDPN5+kgMYjvnFvkxhrginJuhUqmobKdsaTGMzpKRyPCkBBQvwIMAACZnC6MK6CG6qClIohQBQwCDqDRSpAtPiy+X08FzJCAXg3AKU7SAAKjsdkgALIAVQxAAkkAAlACiGPNtoAygBJHYAOSRrL8FKpJTKtOqYKZ8SO7IoGK5PL5gqQ5y+vhVAiEGAwSD0ZBGYBgGCE8CEaVFimUqiR5M+AZpvXpWK0vriR2KaRAGQJp2JjBAJgKytap2bqSQ9nbcM7oY0hSI9l7U-78KHAmIY9yE-r0+Ic-EC4xa0uXSDtbbo3440m01O85VYogS5rdNHp-PECmCevrVv96PdPgI1SL5vleO43ood4ME2RAbNAcCIHaEALGW7CHJckYJsKRAwJwvLKBA-IBmKSH+r6RCVng1Y-iGjINkiDz2Pmf5jPwBZIGAIAANYQP8wAPM8ryCO8nxKr8SDcbxQIgpqOLuHisK5AiU7CSiPGAuitj1tJ0L4nCRKKd8RC4jCHZdjojYRicnLcryApCkmOhkZSVwPiGUlmahFnRlZca2RW-pOZRdZhqZ+4ii2SBttYpxGGxnEmeF24LoOB7DqOkXRRxXGTpus6ViBrSgkuxYZFFMWZRuRwJSqe7fj0dIngBEyvpeH5IF+yWBrV1RPg1F7vnlrVgTVwZqH+z6NUBLVfhB+AxEAA)

Comment: A practical use-case could be to register a base-class custom html element with [CustomElementsRegistry.define](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define) and decide within the constructor which subclasss html element to create (based on the provided html attributes). So `<my-input type='text'>` could apply a different subclass than `<my-input type='checkbox'>`.